# How to save current DOM with Ajax, jQuery and PhP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have edited (appended some of my div's)in my page, now, I need to save all of it, and of course to replace old one.

**DOM body example:**

```
 <body>
  <div id="save_dom">Save</div>

    <div class="box">111</div>
    <div class="box">222</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $(document).on('click', '#save_dom', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/saver.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
          // chose data to send 
          }, success: function(response) {
          // do things if successed
          }
        });
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>
```

**saver.php file example:**

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['data'];
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
file_put_contents($file, $data);
echo'Saved!';
```

Something in this way.

How to save current dom via Ajax, jQuery, PhP?

Comment: `data: document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think it's good to save the DOM in DB..

you can post the dom with Ajax by getting the html of the body

`$("body").html();`

Example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#save_dom', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/saver.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      Dom : $("body").html()
      }, success: function(response) {
      // do things if successed
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: What about php? How to replace old index.html with new data?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html of current page as a string using this code

```
$("html").html()
```

Now pass the string via ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $(document).on('click', '#save_dom', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/saver.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
              //Pass data in ajax
              data:$("html").html()
          }, 
          success: function(response) {
          // do things if successed
          }
        });
      });

    });
</script>
```

The problem will be, this string will contain everything including the javascript, css etc. If you are interested in the html inside body or inside any other element, you can use

```
data:$("body").html()
```

OR

```
data:$("#wrapperElementId").html()
```

Comment: What about php? How to replace old index.html with new data?

Comment: Either use file_put_content or open file in write mode, add the content and save the fiel